# MATLAB: How to turn off "beep" sound?

Tags: matlab, beep

Pardon this silly newbie question but: how can I turn off the extremely annoying "beep" sound that MATLAB makes whenever I (accidentally) hit backspace in the Command Window?

Comment: If it were only with the backspace... :-)

Comment: Who could have thought we have a `beep` tag!

Comment: Have you looked through the preferences panel? Mine doesn’t make a beep, I must have turned it off a long time ago.

Comment: or just mute :)

Answer (score 2):

Just
`beep off`
in the latest versions.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/beep.html

Comment: only works for errors. does not disable the beep for a ton of other annoying circumstances (too many backspaces, down arrow too many times when scrolling through previous commands, etc)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common cause of frustration indeed: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/36303-can-the-beep-be-turned-off-within-matlab.

You can do

```
beep off
```

[`beep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/beep.html) was added long before version 2006a.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that but I still am getting the beep. To confirm, I typed `status = beep` and the output was "status = 'off' ".

Comment: This seems to remove the beep with errors, but not with other situations like backspace (I tested on R2017b)

Comment: `beep` existed way before R2006a. I remember using it in the early 1990’s. The docs say “Introduced before R2006a”. They have been keeping track of when functions were introduced in R2006a, anything that already existed then has the same “before” note.